# how to total clean the folders from /var/spool/abrt/

Tags: rhel, find, abrt

we want to delete all abrt folders from  `/var/spool/abrt/`

before we just run the following , to see how many folders we have

```
find /var/spool/abrt/  -type d
/var/spool/abrt/
/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-09-10-08:05:21-1652
```

now we runs this to clean the abrt folders

```
 find /var/spool/abrt/  -type d   -exec abrt-cli rm '{}' \;
'/var/spool/abrt' is not a problem directory
Can't delete '/var/spool/abrt/': (null)
rm '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-09-10-08:05:21-1652'
find: ‘/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-09-10-08:05:21-1652’: No such file or directory
```

and simple verification

```
 find /var/spool/abrt/  -type d
/var/spool/abrt/
```

note - no folders

but as we can see from command `find /var/spool/abrt/  -type d   -exec abrt-cli rm '{}' \;` output we get also

```
'/var/spool/abrt' is not a problem directory
find: ‘/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-09-10-08:05:21-1652’: No such file or directory
```

just want to be sure if I have something wrong with -  `find /var/spool/abrt/  -type d   -exec abrt-cli rm '{}' \;`  ?

Comment: This is a situation where I would be worried if I did _not_ get those errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your output,

```
'/var/spool/abrt' is not a problem directory
Can't delete '/var/spool/abrt/': (null)
```

is shown because your `find` command matches `/var/spool/abrt` itself, as well as its subdirectories.

```
find: ‘/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2019-09-10-08:05:21-1652’: No such file or directory
```

is shown because `find` tries to descend into that directory, even though `abrt-cli` has removed it.

To avoid the first, tell `find` you want a minimum depth of 1; to avoid the second, prune the directories you delete:

```
find /var/spool/abrt/ -mindepth 1 -type d -exec abrt-cli rm '{}' \; -prune
```